# error in importing java class in jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to import my java class into the jsp

my java filename is `test2.java`
my jsp filename is `test1.jsp`

both the files are in the same folder i.e `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/`

this is my code :

```
<html>
<head><title>Hello World</title></head>
<body>
Hello World!<br/>   
<%@ page import="test2" %>

<%
out.println("Your IP address is " + request.getRemoteAddr());
%>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives error when I run in apache tomcat server.Here is the error:

```
type Exception report

message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.test1_jsp

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.test1_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:177)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Comment: Use *fully qualified class name* inside the import page directive. It should be like `<%@ page import="com.x.y.z.test2" %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things

change your class name to conform to the Java style rules for identifiers: a class name should always start with an upper-case letter.

Give full package.class name in import

Compiler looks for class in WEB-INF/Classes/yourpackage/yourclass

Comment: Do you see your class in above path WEB-INF. How are you deploying your code. Exporting as WAR and putting in webapps?

Comment: I am fairly new to java so please could you elaborate what you are trying to say?

Comment: This might help you in understanding http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html

Comment: This might sound lame but my WEB-INF directory only contains web.xml and nothing else.What should i Do?

Comment: Here is an simple example on create jsp and deployment structure. Pls go thru this. http://oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/tomcat.html?page=1

Answer (score 0):

First put the test2.java in a package, such as com/test/test2
Second, use <%@page import="com.test.test2"%> instead of <%@page import="test2"%>

The application server may have difficulties dealing with class with no package in jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JSP page is under the Web Pages folder of your project..

Also under Source Packages folder, make a new package say sample and put your java file under that and now access this java file on your JSP Page as :

```
<%@page import="sample.test2" %>
```

Java does not import java files stored in default package..You should always put it under a user defined package and then access it.